# Conditional include of PackageReference

Tags: msbuild

We need to include StackExchange.Redis.StrongName for our release builds but StackExchange.Redis for debug builds. Our project is .NET 4.71.

I tried to achieve this in our csproj with:

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis.StrongName" Version="1.2.6" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="1.2.6" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
```

But I'm still getting this error:

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'ConnectionMultiplexer' exists in both 'StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c219ff1ca8c2ce46' and 'StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Either I've misunderstood how Choose works, or am I missing something else? Can you even do what I want to do? If not is there any other way around this?

TVMIA,

Adam.

Comment: Do you have any dependency that used the non-strongname package? also note that VS doesn't re-restore if switching between configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do we need the non-strongname ddll? That's a good question - I'll check. If we can just get by with the strongnamed assembly the problem goes away. Still confused as to why it doesn't work :-/   "also note that VS doesn't re-restore if switching between configurations" - Sorry, I don't follow. Could you explain, please?

Comment: rephrased: do you have both the strong name and the normal package ein your package graph? that can happen if another package depends on it.

Comment: Got it, thanks, I'll follow that up.

Comment: And the guilty party is StackExchange.Redis.Extender which includes StackExchange.Redis whether you want it or not. Since there doesn't appear to be a way of redirecting an assembly of one name to another (i.e. StackExchange.Redis -> StackExchange.Redis.Strongname) we're up the creek without a paddle :-( Thanks for your help, anyway.